# gradle ignores --no-daemon sometimes when running from Jenkins gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gradle-plugin

I'm running different gradle tasks from Jenkins gradle plugin and using invoke gradle and with `--no-daemon` switch. I noticed that sometimes gradle ignores the no daemon switch and start the it anyway (which causes builds to hang).

my environment is:

- Jenkins core 1.565.3
- gradle plugin 1.22
- gradle version used 2.13

EDIT:

also when trying from command line with --no-daemon, the daemon still starts:

```
-bash-4.1$ ps -ef | grep gradle
11831    26400  1920 19 15:33 pts/1    00:00:03 /opt/jdk1.7.0_10//bin/java -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle -classpath /DATA/maas_slave/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/gradle-2.13-rc-1/lib/gradle-launcher-2.13-rc-1.jar org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain --no-daemon zipAlign
11831    26440 26400 20 15:33 pts/1    00:00:03 /opt/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /DATA/maas_slave/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/gradle-2.13-rc-1/lib/gradle-launcher-2.13-rc-1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.13-rc-1
```

and also with -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false in GRADLE_OPTS

```
-bash-4.1$ ps -ef | grep gradle
11831     1918  1920 26 15:50 pts/1    00:00:02 /opt/jdk1.7.0_10//bin/java -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle -classpath /DATA/maas_slave/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/gradle-2.13-rc-1/lib/gradle-launcher-2.13-rc-1.jar org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain zipAlign
11831     1962  1918 29 15:50 pts/1    00:00:02 /opt/jdk1.7.0_10/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /DATA/maas_slave/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/gradle-2.13-rc-1/lib/gradle-launcher-2.13-rc-1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 2.13-rc-1
```

any idea how to ensure that daemon would not start?

Comment: Stumbeld across the same issue... https://discuss.gradle.org/t/daemon-starts-anyway-with-no-daemon-command-line-option/2481 not sure if it is related With a newer gradle version it seems to work however...